# How can my GNOME Shell extension detect the GNOME version?

Tags: gnome-shell-extensions

I'd like to support multiple GNOME versions with my shell extension. How can I detect the GNOME version it's running on and branch the code appropriately?

Comment: By any chance you have been succesfull in setting an IDE to autocomplete Gjs?

Comment: No. I'm not generally familiar with JS autocompletion, but I did have an idea to make TypeScript/Flow annotations for Gnome Shell. That would probably be a big job though, and with Gnome Shell's versioning hell, DefinitelyTyped's infrastructure probably wouldn't work great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
const Config = imports.misc.config;
if (Config.PACKAGE_VERSION.startsWith("3.42"))
    // etc.
```