# How to get OS name while writing gnome-extensions

Tags: gnome-shell-extensions

How to get OS name while writing gnome-extensions..

for example:

```
GLib.get_real_name()
```

I have gone through this post [How can my GNOME Shell extension detect the GNOME version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34120963/how-can-my-gnome-shell-extension-detect-the-gnome-version)

Comment: What do you mean by "OS name" exactly? The distribution name, host name, or...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of getting the operating system name as found in `/etc/os-release`, this not particularly related to GJS or extensions.

You could just open the `/etc/os-release` file directly, but since `GKeyFile` is not introspectable in GJS you would have to parse it manually. Alternatively you could use the `org.freedesktop.hostname1` DBus interface to get the "pretty name", although I don't know if that's guaranteed to be available on all distributions.

```js
const GLib = imports.gi.GLib;
const Gio = imports.gi.Gio;

let osName = 'Unknown';

try {
    // NOTE: this is a synchronous call that will block the main thread
    //       until it completes. Using `Gio.DBus.system.call()` would be
    //       better, but I don't know if that works for your use case.
    let reply = Gio.DBus.system.call_sync(
        'org.freedesktop.hostname1',
        '/org/freedesktop/hostname1',
        'org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties',
        'Get',
        new GLib.Variant('(ss)', [
            'org.freedesktop.hostname1',
            'OperatingSystemPrettyName'
        ]),
        null,
        Gio.DBusCallFlags.NONE,
        -1,
        null
    );

    let value = reply.deep_unpack()[0];
    osName = value.unpack();
} catch (e) {
    logError(e, 'Fetching OS name');
}

// Example Output: "Fedora 32 (Workstation Edition)" or "Unknown" on failure
log(osName);
```